# ASP:Login Control vs. creating your own login control

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-3.5, membership

Is there any security benefit to using the asp:Login control over using just a panel with an asp:textbox for username and password? The OnClick methods still would use membership for validity.

Just wondering if asp:login gives any enhanced security?

Comment: see Securing Login Controls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178346.ASPX

Answer (score 0):

if asp:login gives any enhanced security?
No, It dosen't give you any enhanced security, but you have to write lesser code when you use it.
These controls are just for rapid application development, which comes bundled with all validation and best practice so that they can be just dragged and dropped on the form.

which one should you use?
It depends upon the context. If you are using all the buildin function od the provided framework there is no need to rolling out your own? Why? because you may leave some loopholes like validating etc.